# How to avoid round off error in java?

Tags: java

I'm using following calculation in my Java code. The problem is, despite of our except to dd value have to be "0.3530" , it get "0". What's the missing?

```
double dd = (double) (442 / 1252);
```

Comment: Integer division. `double dd = 442 / (double) 1252;`

Comment: TNX a lot dear @Elliott Frisch. It's works.